# Drawing several objects in OpenGL 4

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to recreate the classic game Asteroids as an exercise into learning OpenGL 4. All the tutorials I've read start out teaching how to draw 1 object (usually a triangle). Well I can't figure out how to draw several objects. I have a ship which is a triangle and asteroids which are octagons. I'm able to draw them but they're all connected.

```
GLfloat ship_vertices[][2] = {
  { -0.05f, -0.05f },
  {  0.05f, -0.05f },
  {  0.00f,  0.05f }
};

struct asteroid
{
  GLfloat asteroid_vertices[num_asteroid_vertices][2];  
};

vector<asteroid> asteroids;

GLuint asteroid_buffer_object;
GLuint ship_buffer_object;
GLuint asteroid_vao;
GLuint ship_vao;


void InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &asteroid_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, asteroid_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(asteroid)*asteroids.size(), &asteroids[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    cout << sizeof(asteroid) << endl;
    cout << asteroids.size() << endl;
    cout << sizeof(asteroid)*asteroids.size() << endl;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &asteroid_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(asteroid_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ship_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ship_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ship_vertices), ship_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &ship_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(ship_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0); 
}

void display()
{
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glUseProgram(theProgram);
  glBindVertexArray(asteroid_vao);

  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, num_asteroid_vertices*asteroids.size());

  glBindVertexArray(ship_vao);
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, num_ship_vertices);

  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glUseProgram(0);

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: you can edit the your own posts if you make a mistake by clicking the edit link below them. no need to delete them

Answer (score 0):

line loop will connect each point to the next and will make no distinction between asteroids (openGL doesn't know that you are trying to draw several asteroids)

You need a for each instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++){
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, num_asteroid_vertices*i, num_asteroid_vertices);
}
```

However [glMultiDrawArrays](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMultiDrawArrays.xhtml) will help with this;

```
GLint[] startindexes = new GLInt[asteroids.size()];
GLsizei[] numberindexes = new GLsizei[asteroids.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++){
    startindexes[i] = num_asteroid_vertices*i;
    numberindexes[i] = num_asteroid_vertices;
}
glMultiDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, startindexes, numberindexes, asteroids.size());
```

There is also a [indirect variant](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml) where those arrays are stored in a VBO